# "Inline literal start-string without end-string" from AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

After I run `aws codebuild create-project help` and then press `q` to exit, my terminal shows:

```
<string>:180: (WARNING/2) Inline literal start-string without end-string.
<string>:309: (WARNING/2) Inline literal start-string without end-string.
<string>:690: (WARNING/2) Inline literal start-string without end-string.
```

I doubt that there's a bug in AWS CLI help, so I assume this is something misconfigured in my own system - but I don't know how to go about debugging it.

This happens even on a fresh terminal created with `Command-N`, so it's not being caused by leftover weirdness from previous commands.

Setup:

- Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6
- iTerm2 3.1.1 / Terminal 2.7.3
- aws-cli/1.11.154 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.7.0 botocore/1.7.12

Comment: Try to use some Text editor like notepad++, then convert `EOL (End Of Line)` to Unix type

Comment: *"I doubt that there's a bug in AWS CLI help"*  That's actually not unheard-of.  I bump into exactly that, on occasion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known [bug](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2383). There is an issue with how Python prints the help string. It should in no way affect the functionality of AWS CLI commands.

Not only for `codebuild`, you will see the same warning for other AWS CLI commands too. It is harmless and hopefully will be fixed in a future version of CLI.